# How to filter with contains RadListBox based on Texbox values using c#?

Tags: c#, telerik

I would like to filter using contains RadListBox based on Textbox values.

Example : 
In my RadListBox, I have following vallues USA, India, Singapore.

While user enter textbox like USA. That time I would like to show only USA & then the remaining values must be hidden. when user remove the textbox values, that time i would like to show all list.

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dropdown-and-listcontrol-dropdownlist-filtering.html)

```
this.radDropDownList1.FilterExpression = "Country LIKE 'USA'";
```

Or:

```
private bool FilterItem(RadListDataItem item)
{
    if (item.Text.StartsWith("USA"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While use FilterExpression I'm getting Error:         'Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBox' does not contain a definition for 'FilterExpression' and no extension method 'FilterExpression' accepting a first
 argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try to use RadDropDownList

Comment: Based on my requirement they are want to filter using RadListBox. How to do it ? Can you please help me to do it ?